# What's the point of the VPERMILPS instruction (_mm_permute_ps)?

Tags: assembly, x86, avx, instruction-set

The AVX instruction set introduced VPERMILPS which seems to be a simplified version of SHUFPS (for the case where both input registers are the same).

For example, the following instruction:

```
c5 f0 c6 c1 00          vshufps xmm0,xmm1,xmm1,0x0
```

can be replaced with:

```
c4 e3 79 04 c1 00       vpermilps xmm0,xmm1,0x0
```

As you can see, the VPERMILPS version takes one byte extra and does the same thing. According to the instruction tables, both of the instructions take 1 CPU cycle and have the same throughput.

What's the point of introducing this kind of instruction? Am I missing something?

Comment: With `vpermilps` there are three 'orthogonal' options: 1. packed single versus packed double, 2. immediate shuffle control integer versus variable control vector, and 3. 128 bits xmm vs 256 bits ymm. Choosing different combinations, this leads to 8 different versions of `vpermilps`. Coincidentally one of them has the same behavior as `vshufps`. Therefore, it wouldn't be logical if `vpermilps xmm0,xmm1,0x0` didn't exist. Nevertheless, one might prefer `vshufps xmm0,xmm1,xmm1,0x0`, which saves one byte indeed. (I'm not sure if this comment is suitable as an answer.)

Comment: The question remains, however, why `vpermilps` with immediate control integers exists at all, because there is also `vshufpd`.

Comment: re: your edit: Only the SSE encoding of `shufps` will leave upper lanes unmodified, and yes that's not available for `vpermilps`.  But your example is `vshufps`, which does zero upper lanes, and can copy-and-shuffle.  I guess that's potentially useful on CPUs where it won't cause an AVX/SSE transition stall (anything except Haswell/Broadwell), like SSE `pinsrd/q` for inserting into a YMM.  I guess it also saves even more code bytes to use SSE1 shufps, if you avoid a REX prefix from xmm8..15.  Just a 2-byte opcode + modrm + imm8 = 4 bytes total, vs. 5 with a 2-byte VEX + opcode.

Answer (score 12):

Yes using `vpermilps`-immediate is normally a missed-optimization vs. `vshufps` (except on Knight's Landing), wasting 1 byte of code size for the same operation with the same performance.

---

I think the main point of `vpermilps` is that it's available with a vector control operand.  Before AVX, the only variable-control shuffle was integer `pshufb`.

> [`VPERMILPS ymm1, ymm2, ymm3/m256`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps)  - Permute single-precision floating-point values in ymm2 using controls from ymm3/m256 and store result in ymm1.

---

But of course the immediate form has a totally separate opcode, and you're asking why *it* exists.  Intel definitely could have included only the vector version, so the question becomes **"why did they include the immediate version?"** It takes at least a bit of extra decode hardware.  The shuffle unit already has hardware to unpack immediate control operands in this form, because it's identical to `vshufps`, so perhaps it was cheap-ish to implement?

The only thing you can do with immediate `vpermilps` that you can't with `vshufps` is **load+shuffle in one instruction**, like `vpermilps ymm0, [rdi], 0b00011011` to reverse the elements in each lane of the source.  But like most instructions with an immediate, it can't micro-fuse a memory operand so it's still 2 fused-domain uops for the front end.  (On AMD CPUs, it actually does save front-end bandwidth.)  Still, it saves code-size vs. `vmovups ymm0, [rdi]` / `vshufps ymm0,ymm0,ymm0, 0b00011011`.

Other than that, I don't see much point.  They both do the same shuffle in both 128-bit lanes, reusing the 4x 2-bit fields of the immediate for both lanes.  (While [`vpermilpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMILPD.html) and [`vshufpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPD.html) both use 1-bit fields in their immediates, and can do different shuffles in each lane; the upper lane uses bits 2 and 3.  And the ZMM versions use bits 4..7 for the upper 256.  So again `vpermilpd dst, src, imm` is identical to `vshufpd dst, src,src, imm`, unless you use a memory source or you use a shuffle-control vector instead of immediate.)

It makes you wonder if Intel forgot that VEX encoding was going to enable non-destructive `vshufps` to do the same thing for immediate shuffles.

---

**Or maybe they had in mind their low-power CPUs, like Knight's Landing (Xeon Phi), where a 1-source shuffle is cheaper:**

`vpermilps` has 1-cycle throughput there, but `vshufps` or `vperm2f128` has 2-cycle throughput and an extra cycle of latency.  (According to [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/).)

So using `vshufps` with the same input twice is slower there.

But on Intel's big-core mainstream CPUs, yes using `vpermilps`-immediate is a missed-optimization vs. `vshufps`, unless you can use it with a memory source.  `vshufps` would need the same memory source twice, which obviously isn't encodeable.

**AVX was designed years ahead of KNL, but maybe the ISA designers had in mind that maybe some future CPU could be more efficient with a simpler shuffle.**

Regular Silvermont (out-of-order Atom that KNL is based on) doesn't support AVX, but it has 1 uop / 1-cycle throughput and latency for `shufps`.  Goldmont has 0.5c throughput for `shufps`.

AFAIK, Intel still hasn't made a low-power core (other than Xeon Phi) with AVX.  I don't think they're planning to with [Tremont](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/tremont) or Gracemont, successors to Goldmont Plus.